# MongoDB - Adding large number of child records over time causes OpLog issues

Tags: mongodb

We have an application that stores a parent record and then telemetry information that we capture from vehicles. The telemetry information comes in approximately every second and we add that as a child document to the parent record.
An example of the document with two telemetry records (note there are lot more fields than are shown below):

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("654d76b8667a5972b20f06d9"),
    "deviceIdentifier" : "TEST1",
    "pathId" : NumberInt(300887),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2023-11-10T00:17:59.310+0000"),
    "path" : [
        {
          "eventTime" : "2022-02-11T06:00:11.000Z",
          "timestamp" : "2022-02-11T06:00:11.000Z",
          "speed" : NumberInt(50),
          "lat" : -43.8678108049212,
          "lng" : 172.552684388425,
        },
    {
          "eventTime" : "2022-02-11T06:00:12.000Z",
          "timestamp" : "2022-02-11T06:00:12.000Z",
          "speed" : NumberInt(50),
          "lat" : -43.8679108049212,
          "lng" : 172.552784388425,
        }
    ],
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2023-11-10T00:17:59.310+0000")
}
```

The new records are added using the $push command as shown below.

```
await VehiclePathConnection.findOneAndUpdate(
   { pathId, deviceIdentifier },
   {
      ...pathAggregateMeta,
      $push: { path: { $each: points, $sort: { timestamp: 1 } } },
   },
   { upsert: true }
);
```

We have a Mongo cluster that is hosted in Mongo Atlas with three nodes. When we start getting data we see major Mongo issues with the OpLog GB/Hr metric spiking upwards. Eventually it becomes too much and Mongo becomes unresponsive and crashes. It appears this is because we are adding more and more data to the single document and this is then being replicated across the nodes.

What's the best approach for storing data like this in Mongo? Should we not be storing the telemetry data inside the parent record? Or is there a better way of doing updates?

This is an issue for us with a single vehicle sending telemetry information and so clearly we are doing something fundamentally wrong.

Comment: I think it would make more sense to store it as independent entries rather than using an array.

Comment: Otherwise indexing `pathId` and `deviceIdentifier` should help a bit

Comment: ideal would be to just store `{deviceIdentifier, pathId, eventTime, timestamp, speed, lat, lng}`

Comment: "_The telemetry information comes in approximately every second_" - maybe a use case for a Time Series collection?

Comment: Yes this is a good candidate for a time-series collection. What rough cardinality are you looking at (how many vehicles)?

Comment: Probably dozens of simultaneous vehicles.